# Is there a way to "force" z-index of childrens?

Tags: html, css

This is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/BhQNr/2/) :

## HTML

```
<div class="item">
    &nbsp;
</div>

<div class="item">
    <div class="item-abs">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    &nbsp;
</div>​
```

## CSS

```
.item
{
    position:relative;
    z-index:5;
    float:left;
    background-color:red;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin:10px;
}

.item-abs
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:40px;
    z-index:500;
    background-color:blue;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;    
}
​
```

as you can see, if children have got 500 of z-index, is under the next parents. Is there a way to force the children z-index? Get riding the stack of the father? Or this scenario can't be done?

I can't change z-index of parents, and I'd like to do it without setting a proper descent z-index with javascript...

Comment: No you can't do this because each parent creates a new z-index context.

Comment: @mdk: Have you got a reference for how this works? I thought that a higher z-index meant it would be on top...

Comment: higher z-index doesn't mean it always on top, It depends on stacking context. please read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index/The_stacking_context

Comment: I think I get what you mean now. Each of the relatively positioned elements was working out who was on top, etc. on its own and ignoring anything outside itself. Which makes sense if you are taking it out of the positioning flow...

Comment: @Chris Yeah that's right, stacking context is what I was thinking of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure there is, you don't even need to set the z-index of the child.

Just set the z-index of the last div to a lower z-index, and you are done.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/BhQNr/4/)

The reason for this behaviour is the following: If parents have the same z-index, the one coming last in the DOM "wins". So technically a simple `z-index:1` on your parent with the absolute child would be enough. Other possibility is to set the z-index just on the child:

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/BhQNr/5/)

Comment: Yeah, ok, but must be "dynamic" : if absolute is on the first, it fails again :) http://jsfiddle.net/BhQNr/7/

Comment: Why do you set z-index on the parents? Try the second way i suggested.

Comment: There is a motivation! I drag the div with some plugins, they must have z-index...

Comment: @markzzz if you set the z-index of all parents to the same Value, you can as well set no z-index at all - it's the same effect. You could give the parents decreasing values of z-indices but then the child might be overlapped by the preceding element.

Answer (score 0):

The following fiddle seems to do what you want (I believe):

http://jsfiddle.net/BhQNr/3/

This is done by removing the positioning on the parent elements and making the child relative (it works with absolute but the left and top values are closer than when using absolute).

Comment: Ehm, this change the whole structure of the page! Can't do it :)

Comment: Well it does what you want in the fiddle. ;-) (in FF at least)